# SSRS/CRM: No dropdown list shown

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have a followup problem to my [previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933562/ssrs-getting-a-specific-value-from-different-rows-of-a-dataset)

I have got the list for a single client and a specific year. But now I have to create a dropdown list so the user can choose the year for which the abscence/presence list will be generated.

To achieve this I've created a dataset which generates years (from this year to a specific year in the past). This dataset fills a parameter (CRM_Year) with the year values. At last I filter the dataset which provides the abscence/presence values by the parameter.

My problem is that when I preview the report I can see the dropdown list with the year values but when I upload the report to the CRM and try to run it I get the following error message:

```
[MissingParameterException: The 'CRM_Year' parameter is missing a value]
```

I never even get to see the ddl in the CRM. I'm totally puzzled at what could be the solution to fix this. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You could try deleting the report on the server and re-uploading it. You may have the same problem I noted at the [top of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12901099/419956): settings for report parameters are "set" the first time you upload a report, and won't be updated when a new version of a report is uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it. After I posted the question here I rebuilt the report from scratch, taking only one piece after another and testing it in the CRM.

This worked out very well for me although my solution is identical as the one before. So I think this solution can be a variation for the solution posted by [Jeroen.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419956/jeroen)

Answer (score 2):

I would try renaming the parameter to something without the CRM_ since there are a few reserved parameters that start with that.  I have done what you are attempting, so it should be possible.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'll take it in consideration for the future. But here it didn't make the trick.